# facing error: ProgrammingError: LOB variable no longer valid after subsequent fetch

Tags: python-2.7, clob, cx-oracle

I fetched records from database to mylist and then want to use .decode function on each of the list elements, but that gives me AttributeError: 'cx_Oracle.LOB' object has no attribute 'decode', so I am trying to convert elements into string before using .decode function but I am facing below error for some elements in list:

mylist[rr] = [str(x) for x in mylist[rr]]

ProgrammingError: LOB variable no longer valid after subsequent fetch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few options available here:

(1) upgrade to cx_Oracle 6.x which eliminated this error

(2) use an iterator to process the cursor instead of cursor.fetchall()

(3) if the CLOBs being returned are reasonably small use an output type handler to convert the LOB to a string which improves performance as well due to reduced round-trips to the database (see https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/blob/master/samples/ReturnLobsAsStrings.py)

Hopefully one of those options will work for you!

Comment: 3 is not an option as my CLOBS pretty long, 2- m not using any fetchall function, in robot framework I am using Query keyword to fetch rows to a list and then passing this list to python function, 1 seems to be the only option for me but when I run command prompt: python -m pip install cx_Oracle --upgrade it gives me message "Requirement already up-to-date: cx-Oracle in c:\program files (x86)\python27\li
\site-packages"

Comment: I tried installing it using command: python -m pip install cx_Oracle --upgrade and got message: Successfully installed cx-Oracle-5.1.2, it is not upgrading It to 6, I also tried downloading .whl file for cx_oracle 6 and used command: pip install cx_Oracle-6.3.1-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl but received error message: cx_Oracle-6.3.1-cp27-cp27m-win32.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform, my windows os is 64bit, couldn't find any .whl file for 64bit

Comment: Not sure why pip isn't finding things for you. But you can download the wheel directly: https://pypi.org/project/cx_Oracle/#files. Note that you need to pick the 64-bit Windows (amd64).

Comment: update: it looks like though it gave me message ''Successfully installed cx-Oracle-5.1.2", it actually installed 6, I can see it in lib folder. Thanks.